# UIView animation snaps into place without moving

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uiviewanimation, uiswitch

I'm trying to do a simple animate of a `UIView` and the problem is that the view doesn't expand/collapse as I want it to do, it only snaps to the end of the animation without moving there. Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)policeReportedChanged:(id)sender {
    if (self.policeReportedSwitch.isOn) {
        [self.policeReportNumberColl setHidden:NO];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                         animations:^
         {
             [self.policeReportNumberColl setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 130, 320, 65)];
             [self.damageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 200)];
         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished)
         {

         }
         ];



    } else {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                         animations:^
         {
             [self.policeReportNumberColl setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
             [self.damageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 135, 320, 200)];
         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished)
         {
             [self.policeReportNumberColl setHidden:YES];
         }
         ];

    }
```

I have set the animation to reveal the UIView `policeReportNumberColl` when the switch is turned on and collapsed when it isn't. `damageView` is a UIView below that should move up or down to take the space where the revealed view are or not. Inside `policeReportNumberColl` are one `UILabel` and one `UITextfield`.

I have checked around a lot but can't find anything  other than this should work.

**EDIT:**

I have played around a bit and figured out that it has something to to with which object is sending the action. It DOES work it I connect the animation to a `Touch up inside` on a `UIButton` but it does NOT work if I use `on Value Changed` on my `UISwitch` like I want to. See code below:

```
//Does work
- (IBAction) buttonClicked
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                     animations:^
     {
         [self.damageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         NSLog(@"Klar");
     }
     ];

}

//Does NOT Work
- (IBAction)switchValueChanged {


    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                     animations:^
     {
         [self.damageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         NSLog(@"Klar");
     }
     ];
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how to do this on a `UISwitch onValueChanged`?

Comment: It's been quite a while that I haven't been into animations, but shouldn't you `commitAnimations` after setting it up?
`[UIView commitAnimations];`

Comment: @Neeku Hi, that is only when you use the old way of doing animations, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18907703/1436948 . I have tried doing it the other way as well

Comment: Ah, alright then. But do try different methods to see which works. This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18184412/uiview-animation-not-working-to-resize-view
There are other ways of implementing animation, too; with `QuartzCore`, etc.

Comment: try to turn off autolayout

Comment: @NeilGaliaskarov Hi, Thanks but it is off

Comment: What if you launch the animation from a timer ? does it change anything ?

Comment: @EinoGourdin I tried with a delay in the animation with the same result. Is there something else you were thinking about?

Comment: Yes, can you try to call the animate method from a different function, which you launch with an NSTimer ? Maybe there's something with the onValueChanged that flushes the animation stack or something. Also, did you check if it's called on the main thread ?

Comment: It turns out that it was a bug in the DCRoundSwitch I was using and someone had already pointed out the issue and gived a solution on GitHub: https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCRoundSwitch/issues/30 Thanks everyone for replying!